# C++ bit7z Unresolved External Symbol _imp_CharUpperW@4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to use bit7z in my C++ code to create a program that zips a directory. I'm receiving a LNK2019 error for something called _imp_CharUpperW@4 in my bit7z_d.lib. My IDE is Visual Studio Community 2019 and I use C++ 20.
These are my files:

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <bit7z.hpp>
#include "main.h"
#include <bitcompressor.hpp>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
using namespace bit7z;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::string path = "C:/Users/aretz/Downloads/test";
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
    std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}

void AIXLogger::CompressDir() {
        Bit7zLibrary lib{ L"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.dll" };
        BitCompressor compressor{ lib, BitFormat::Zip };

        vector< wstring > files = { L"C:/Users/aretz/Downloads/test" };
        wstring zip = { L"output_archive.zip" };


        compressor.compressFiles( files , zip );
}

void AIXLogger::Execute() {
    CompressDir();
}
```

main.h

```
#pragma once
#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qobject.h>
#include <bit7z.hpp>

class AIXLogger : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:

public:

    void CompressDir();
    void Execute();
};
```

aixLogger.pro

```
# ----------------------------------------------------
# This file is generated by the Qt Visual Studio Tools.
# ------------------------------------------------------

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = aixLogger
DESTDIR = ./Debug
CONFIG += debug console
DEPENDPATH += .
MOC_DIR += .
OBJECTS_DIR += debug
UI_DIR += GeneratedFiles
RCC_DIR += GeneratedFiles


include(aixLogger.pri)
```

Screenshots of my Properties are here:
[Additional Include Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYR1J.png)
[Additional Library Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Bpo.png)
[Additional Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0ZZ1.png)

This is the exact error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CharUpperW@4 referenced in function "wchar_t __cdecl MyCharUpper(wchar_t)" (?MyCharUpper@@YA_W_W@Z)   aixLogger   D:\local\aretz\Programmierung\git-workplace\aixLogger\bit7z_d.lib(MyString.obj) 1

Comment: Bit7z is a static library that uses WinAPI function `CharUpperW`. You have to explicitly link with `User32.lib`.